# How to excuse an undeclared variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables

Recently I've been creating a game but I'm having a problem. To calculate what you've hit on an enemy it uses the variable **sword**.

At this point the player may or may not have purchased a sword, therefore I get an error that says: "variable not declared". Is there a way to work around a variable that hasn't been declared yet?

Comment: Could we see some sample code, perhaps?

Comment: The best way is to ensure that you initialize variables before attempting to use them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options.

The first is to ensure that a player always has a `sword` variable.  Set it to `None` before the player obtains a sword and, when you need to know whether the player has a sword, check whether the variable is `None`:

```
 sword = None

 # do lots of stuff here

 if sword is None:
    print 'Hey, no sword!'
 else:
    print 'Chop, chop, chop!'
```

Another way to write this *if sword is not allowed to be an empty string or an integer value of 0* is:

```
 if sword:
    print 'Chop, chop, chop.'
```

Your second option is to wrap every reference to the sword variable in a try block and swallow the NameError that might be raised:

```
 try:
    if sword == 10:
        print 'Choppity chop chop chop.'
 except NameError:
    pass
```

The first solution is (much) better.

Comment: If you mean the missing second = sign, I fixed it.  If you're querying why sword is compared to an integer value, it's simply as an example.  These kind of games usually assign a damage value to weapons, which might simply be the value assigned to sword or, if sword is a richer object, one might look at `sword.damage` or something similar.

Comment: also, `then` word is not python

Comment: Oops, thanks!  That's what I get from programming having both Komodo and Delphi open while trying to answer questions on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks, helped me get over my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code, I would say the usual way to "excuse a variable that hasn't been declared yet" would be by handling the possibility of a `NameError` exception.

```
try: 
  # variable sword may or may not exist here..
  sword
except NameError:
  # handle this
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. What wim has offered is fine but if your variable is actually a key in a dict then you can shorten it like so:

```
has_sword = my_items.get('sword', False)
```

The second value in the `get()` method is a default value for when the sword key doesn't exist.

PRO TIP: globals() and locals() provide direct access to variables declared in the global scope and in a function respectively. That means `globals().get('sword', False)` should be valid for a variable you've declared globally.

Finally, as wim suggests you aren't really going about this the right way. A more pythonic approach would be to use a class like this:

```
class Player():
  def __init__(self)
    self.sword = None

player = Player()
if player.sword:
  print "Off with his head!"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the full extent of your game.  Is "sword" the only item that the player character can carry, or is their an implied inventory that is open ended?  (e.g. the player character has a sack or backpack and can pick up items during game play.)

If you would like to give the character an inventory, you can use a simple list, or, if all items are unique - i.e. the character can have only ONE sword at a time, then a set would be appropriate.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = set( )

    @property
    def has_sword(self):
        return ('sword' in self.inventory)

me = Player( )
me.inventory.add('sword')
if me.has_sword:
    print "swish!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variable exist in your globals or locals dict, or use :

```
try:
    a = b
except NameError:
    a = b = 1
```